# Swift - Return for this function

Tags: swift, closures

I'm a beginner and I did this function only to called getMovieById() on my viewDidLoad. But now I need to call this function in another place, receiving something. I have to receive an imdbID to pass to my Alamofire request function and I need to return my movieDetailed, how can I do this?

```
func getMovieById(){
    let requestURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID!)"

    print("|getMovieIdFromAPI|   URL: \(requestURL)")

    Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in
        print("|Alamofire request|   Response is: \(response)")

        let movieResult = response.result.value
        let movieDetailed: Movie = Movie()

        if let title = movieResult?.title {
            print("Title: \(title)")
            self.movTitleLabel.text = title
            movieDetailed.title = title
        }

        // Lots of irrelevant code removed here                

        if let movieImdbID = movieResult?.imdbID {
            movieDetailed.imdbID = movieImdbID
        }

        if self.fromFavorite {
            self.addButton.title = "Remove"
        }
    }//Alamofire.request
}//getMovieByID()
```

Just for the record, my Movie class is:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import AlamofireObjectMapper

class Movie: Mappable {
    var posterURL  : String?
    var title      : String?
    var runtime    : String?
    var director   : String?
    var actors     : String?
    var genre      : String?
    var plot       : String?
    var production : String?
    var released   : String?
    var year       : String?
    var imdbID     : String?
    var imdbRating : String?

    init() { }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        posterURL  <- map["Poster"]
        title      <- map["Title"]
        runtime    <- map["Runtime"]
        director   <- map["Director"]
        actors     <- map["Actors"]
        genre      <- map["Genre"]
        plot       <- map["Plot"]
        production <- map["Production"]
        released   <- map["Released"]
        year       <- map["Year"]
        imdbID     <- map["imdbID"]
        imdbRating <- map["imdbRating"]
    }
}
```

Any help?

---

### Update

So, my MovieViewController now is this:

```
import UIKit
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire
import Kingfisher

class MovieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    /* Outlets */

    var imdbID: String?
    var fromFavorite: Bool = false
    var movieDelegate: MovieDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getMovie(imdbID: imdbID!)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let spinnerActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            spinnerActivity.label.text = "Loading";
            spinnerActivity.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
        }
    }


    func getMovie(imdbID: String){

            let requestURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID)"

            Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in

            let movieResult = response.result.value
            let movieDetailed: Movie = Movie()

        /* Irrelevant code - If let for any item of movie */

            if self.fromFavorite {
                self.addButton.title = "Remove"
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
            }

            self.movieDelegate?.didGetDetails(movie: movieDetailed)

        }//Alamofire.request

    }//getMovie()


func showAlertButton(tile: String, msg: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: tile, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Action for my addButton
@IBAction func addAsFavorite() {
    if (!self.fromFavorite) {

        saveMovieOnDB(movieID: self.imdbID!, onCompletion: {
            (isFavorite) in

                if isFavorite {
                    self.showAlertButton(tile: "Error", msg: "You already saved this movie as favorite")
                }       
                else {
                    self.showAlertButton(tile: "Saved", msg: "The movie was saved in your favorites list")
                }      
            })
        }  
        else {
            removeFromFavorites(movieID: self.imdbID!, onCompletion: {
                self.showAlertButton(tile: "Removed", msg: "The movie was removed from favorites list")
            })
        }
    }

} //MovieControler
```

Now, my FavoritesViewController for my CollectionView (that will be show the movies saved):

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Kingfisher


protocol MovieDelegate {
    func didFavorite(imdbID: String)
    func didGetDetails(movie: Movie)
}


class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var favCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var movies = [Movie]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.favCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.favCollectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let spinnerActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            spinnerActivity.label.text = "Loading";
            spinnerActivity.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
        }

        //Database(Parse) function
        getMovieCollection(onCompletion: {
            (objects) in

            var moviesIDs = [String]()
            var auxArray = [Movie]()

            for obj: PFObject in objects! {

                //Getting the IDs saved in my database
                moviesIDs.append(obj["imdbID"] as! String)

            }

            for movieID: String in moviesIDs {
                print("|Fav CollectionView| - Getting movie by id")

                /* for each ID on my moviesIDs array I'll do a search by ID using getMovie() and add each movie to an array of movies that will be show on my collection view */
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true);
            }

        })    
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.movies.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FavCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell

        let imgStg: String = movies[indexPath.row].posterURL!
        let imgURL: URL = URL(string: imgStg)!

        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL, cacheKey: imgStg)
        cell.favPosterImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)


        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueFromFavorite" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? MovieViewController {
                let cell = sender as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell
                let indexPath = self.favCollectionView!.indexPath(for: cell)?.row
                let movieSelectedID = self.movies[indexPath!].imdbID

                destination.imdbID = movieSelectedID!
                destination.fromFavorite = true

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Problems/Questions

1. The app is crashing when I click on Add button. (this button is on my navigation bar and it should change his title to "Remove" once the movie is on my collection view). The console show this error:

   2017-05-03 02:10:27.080 Favorite Movies[1658:36995] -[Favorite_Movies.MovieViewController addAsFavorite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fca7456a270
   2017-05-03 02:10:27.092 Favorite Movies[1658:36995] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Favorite_Movies.MovieViewController addAsFavorite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fca7456a270'

Any idea of what is causing this? (Maybe is related to the next question)

2. How can I call my getMovie() in that for - in my CollectionView? (for each id that I get from my database I should search for the movie by id, returning the movie details).

Comment: So Alamofire is asynchronous meaning everything inside responseObject callback will be executed after the function returns so you can change it to a synchronous method but before I show you that why are trying to return a Movie object? Are you trying to fill a TableView? To just display the data on a view?

Comment: I'm trying to save this movie in my database and at the same time show it in a collection view. (I search for a movie, the result is showed in a table view, user click in one movie and show the details in a view. In this view there is a button to add as favorite movie. So I'll save in my database and add in a array of favMovies, to show in a collection view)

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly then getMovieById is for the detail view which is separate from the collection view. You are just trying to get more details about the movie the user selected on a previous view. You're right you want to call getMovieById from viewDidLoad but the correct way is to start a loading indicator on the screen first because again it is a network call can take a second or minutes depending on the internet connection. Then at the end on the responseObject callback you want to you remove the indicator and display everything. If this is correct I will provide a sample.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm using MBProgressHUD for that. Is not that much effective, the load just blink but it is working. I'm calling MBProgressHUD before let movieResult = response.result.value and calling its hide at the end of my getMovieById function. In fact in my collection view I'll need to call this Alamofire request again. So my goal would be make a function only for the request and then call this function inside of my getMovieByID() function. So getMovieByID receive a imdbID, that will be received by Alamofire. At the end, getMovieByID returns a movieDetails of model Movie.

Comment: `Movie` can have no name, or it can have a name that changes. Are you sure that's reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

I am still a bit confused on what your asking because having a web call return a value synchronous is not a good idea. But I hope this helps you with what your looking for. If not comment and I will try to change.

Protocol for Communication between detail and collection

```
protocol MovieDelegate {
    func didFavorite(movieId: String)
    func didGetDetails(movie: Movie)
}
```

Collection ViewController

```
class MoviesViewController: UICollectionViewController, MovieDelegate {
     let movieIds = [String]()

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let selectedMovieId = self.movieIds[indexPath.row]
         // Perform segue here
         self.perfomSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: selectedMovieId)
     }

     func didFavorite(movieId: String) {
         // Change collection view accordingly.
     }

     func didGetDetails(movie: Movie) {
         // Do something with the Movie object
     }

     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
         if let destination = segue.destination as? MovieDetailViewController {
             destination.imdbID = sender as! String
             destination.movieDelegate = self
         }
    }
}
```

Detail ViewController

```
class MovieDetailViewController: UIController {

    var imdbID: String!
    var movieDelegate: MovieDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       getMovie(imdbID)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        // Start loading indicator here
    }

    func getMovie(imdbID: String) {
       Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{
           let movie = Movie()
           // Fill Movie object based off the response

           // Create a view based off Movie object

           // Stop loading indicator      

           // Let the collection view know we now have details for this movie.     
           self.movieDelegate.didGetDetails(movie)
       }
    }

    func didTapFavorite() {
        // Let the collection view know the user favorited the movie.
        self.movieDelegate.didFavorite(self.imdbID)
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

1 The reason you are getting crashes on button is because your @IBAction needs to be.

```
@IBAction func addAsFavorite(sender: Any)
```

2 Now I understand what you want so you don't need a protocol unless you want to update when a favorite is unfavorited.

Here is what you want.

```
for movieID: String in moviesIDs {
    print("|Fav CollectionView| - Getting movie by id")

    /* for each ID on my moviesIDs array I'll do a search by ID using getMovie() and add each movie to an array of movies that will be show on my collection view */

    Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in

        let movieResult = response.result.value
        let movie: Movie = Movie()

        /* Irrelevant code - If let for any item of movie */

        self.movies.append(movie)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Some questions: Where do I put protocol? There is a convention? 2. You're calling getMovie receiving movieID on viewDidLoad, but when you declare the function, there is nothing to receive. Is this right? I'll put getMovie(imdbID: String) - this ID is a string, not an Int. 3. This self.delegate.didGetDetails has an error... xcode is saying that "Value of type 'MovieViewController'has no member 'delegate'.

Comment: The protocol can be anywhere, even in its own file I would put it above the CollectionViewController. Will edit the answer to fix the other issues

Comment: maybe I missunderstood, but I guess, this way you are going from collection view to details view, right? I'm little confused because in my case, first I get a table view, select a item from this table view and get the ID from this item, did a search by ID (now on my MovieViewController) and show the details on this view. OK! This view have an "add" button, the user will click and this movie goes to my FavoritesCollectionView. The only way user goes from favorites to details is when he wants to remove from favorites. I'm sorry but I'm not understanding what would I put in this protocols.

Comment: Okay now I am understanding better so this is the layout right.

TableView of a lot of movies.

Comment: Yes, the table view is ok. TableView has a segue that pass an imdbID of the movie clicked. My MovieViewController receive this imdbID and receives from API all the movie details. To save on my database I need the imdbID from this movieDetailed. I was trying movieDetailed.imdbID! but since this is inside my function (that was returning nothing) I was stuck. Now I see your idea but how can I get the imdbID there?

Comment: First TableView of a lot of movies.
Then the user selects a movies from the TableView.
Now we display a detail view of the movie selected.
If it is favorite then we save it to storage.

Now if the user goes back there is a favorites screen which you would now like the movie just favorited to appear in.
If a movie in favorited screen is selected then you go to the detail where you can unfavorite.
If it is unfavorited then when they go back you would like to be removed.

Comment: Yes! I guess you got it! MovieView will show an Add button if the movie is not in my CollectionView, is the movie is already favorited, the button will be "remove" that will remove from my collectionView/database. (I'm using parse to store the data. the function to save and delete is already implemented)

Comment: So are you wondering when you need to save it inside your database?

Comment: I did what you suggested but now I don't know how to populate my collection view with the ids I'm getting on my database. I updated my question with my FavoritesViewController (set for my CollectionView). Could you, please, take a look... Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143239/discussion-between-jack-mata-and-u23r).